# How can I deselect all other buttons in array when one is selected?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, if-statement, func

Currently when I select a button in my array it will turn from gray to black and turn back to gray if selected again, which I want.  The issue is when I select one button and select another they will both be black.  How can I make it so when I select one button, then select another, the previous one will go back to gray?

```
let subjectArray = ["Button1", "Button2", "Button3", "Button4"]   
for title in subjectArrary {
                let button = UIButton()
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                button.setTitle("\(title)", for: .normal)
                button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
                button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
                button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

                stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
            }



    func buttonPressed(sender:AnyObject) {

            guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }

            if !button.isSelected {
                button.isSelected = true
                button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            } else {
                button.isSelected = false
                button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is your array of buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reset the state of other buttons when new button is pressed then you could make use of the following code,

```
/**
 Reset the default state of the buttons
 */
func resetButtonStates() {
    for button in [YOUR_BUTTON_ARRAY_VARIABLE_HERE] {
        button.isSelected = false
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
    }
}

func buttonPressed(sender:AnyObject) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }

    // Check wether the button is selected already, to be used as mentioned below
    let isAlreadySelected = sender.isSelected == true

    // Reset the default state to all the buttons
    resetButtonStates()

    // Now update the button state of the selected button alone if its not selected already
    if !isAlreadySelected {
        button.isSelected = true
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    } else {
        // Do Nothing since as per your case if you selected the already selected button it should change to disable right, so the resetButtonStates() will do that.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create an array of buttons which will hold all of your buttons
// This is a class property, we can already initialise this with empty array so we don't need to set it during class init()
let buttons: [UIButton] = [] 

func createButton(withTitle title: String) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .selected) // Please take note I've added this line
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}

func setupButtons() {
    let subjectArray = ["Button1", "Button2", "Button3", "Button4"]   

    for title in subjectArrary {
        let button = createButton(withTitle: title)
        buttons.append(button) // Append all your buttons
        stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
}

func didTapButton(_ button: UIButton) {
    deselectAllButtons()
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected // set/unset of button state happens here
}

func deselectAllButtons() {
    buttons.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
}
```

This line will set black title color to your button when it is selected..

```
button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .selected)
```

For a cleaner code, i've extracted the codes inside your for loop, made a small chunks of methods..
also, no need to add my code comments into your actual code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NotificationCenter`.

1. Define a custom notification name.
2. Subscribe all your buttons to listen to the notification using the method: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(...`.
3. In the **control action** method of your button class, post the notification with `object` (i.e., the sender of the notification) set to `self`.
4. In the **notification handler** method registered with the notification, check for the notification's `object` property. If it is **not** equal to `self`, deselect the current button.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an outlet collection:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

You can detect which is selected

```
func buttonPressed(sender:AnyObject) {

        guard let currentButton = sender as? UIButton else { return }

        buttons.forEach{ (element) in
                if element == currentButton {
                      //change state and params for current button
                }else{
                     //change other buttons
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when u creating buttons u can add them into a array such like

```
let bs = [UIButton]()    
for title in subjectArrary {
    let b = .......
    bs.append(b)
}
```

and in the action method

```
for b in bs {
    b.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
}
(sender as? UIButton).setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating an array of buttons

```
var buttonArray = [UIButton]()


func buttonPressed(sender:AnyObject) {
    let _ = buttonArray.map({$0.isSelected = false})
    sender.isSelected = true
}
```

this will do the trick